# initializing queue with condition

Tags: python, initialization, queue

You have to implement the methods for the class m_sorted_list, which when initialized takes a parameter sorted which is true or false. When the parameter is true the list is sorted in ascending order. When the parameter is false it acts as a normal unbounded queue

that's what I'm given to code

so far, I've done

```
def __init__(self, m_sorted):
    self.__items=[]
    self.__size=0
```

initialization actually wants

–Initialization of the class with parameter which is true or false

seriously, I'm new in Python, I don't really understand what the question is actually want me to do.

can anyone help me what to do?

Comment: can I just do m_sorted=False?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry if I am understanding wrong but the follwoing might help.

```
class N:
    def __init__(self):
        self.s = []
    def add(self,u):
        self.s.append(u)
    def check(self):
        if sorted(self.s) == True:
            print "List is sorted"
        else:
            print "Not sorted but it will sort now"
            return sorted(self.s)
```

Comment: thank you so much, I'll try with it....Anyway with your help, I can actually start studying

Comment: Not a problem. However I have done some edits for making full functional class.

Comment: I've done the class. If you don't mind you can tell me and let me study your code so that I can learn different method. Thank you.